# Is it possible to upload a Poster Frame image for a YouTube Partner via API?

Tags: youtube-api

A client of mine is a YouTube Partner and can upload/set posterframes in their videos that are being uploaded and managed via the API. However, they would like the ability to upload and set these images in the application that has been written for them to manage all of their video assets.

I'd like to be able to upload a poster image (or at worse provide a timecode to grab an approximate frame of video) to set the posterframe on upload and/or via updates after it's been uploaded.

Is this possible for Partners? or are Partners restricted to having to manually do this in the YouTube UI?

Answer (score 1):

There's a new [thumbnails.set()](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/thumbnails/set) method that's part of the YouTube Data API v3. Anyone who has the ability to set a custom thumbnail via any other mechanism (i.e. manually via the YouTube website) can accomplish the same thing using that API call.

Comment: There's no publicly accessible method of setting thumbnails using v2 of the Data API.

Comment: a couple years late here but [prettyembed.js](https://github.com/mike-zarandona/PrettyEmbed.js) can do this